# Remote assistance cannot connect to windows XP from a Windows XP pc

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, remote-desktop, remote-assistance

I am trying to use Remote assistance feature which is provided in all version of windows OS.We are using invitation file to connect to another pc.In our case server PC is windows XP and it can be accessed from windows 8 properly. But when i try to access from windows XP we get error like

```
remote assistance connection could not be established because the invitation has either expired or was canceled
```

Steps i have done to resolve the problem:

I have recreated invitation and checked.But problem still persists.
Checked antivirus and firewall setting.But it didn't solve the issue.
So please help me on solving this problem.

Comment: Did you check time settings are the same on both machines?

Comment: Yes, time setting and regional setting of both pc are same